How to get my application to update when a new version is detected within my repository on github?
Background
For my job, I have made a windows .exe which is a python pyqt5 application that my analysts can use for their work. What I am trying to do is set up a workflow with the help of git that would work something like this:

I make a new change to the application code for the exe
I push the change to my github repo
when the analysts run the .exe, a pop up shows up saying that there is a new version available and asks them if they want to update the app and restart it.

So far, I have been able to push a change from another branch called "develop", when I merge develop into master, I change the application file (called my_qt_app.py) and also increment the version within my file called version_info.txt by bumping the patch number; this is just for testing so I can provoke a new update on master branch when i switch to master after merging develop -> master on my remote. and from my local repository containing master (which doesn't have the updated changes of the remote master), I run the application (again, called my_qt_app.py) and see that there is a new version available on the remote server. (THIS IS THE BEHAVIOR I WANT TO HAPPEN ;) ) I run a subprocess command within the app file to pull from my repo, however, when the application is restarted to see if the application has changed, the code doesn't change, the only change that happens is my file called "version_info.txt". When in reality, I want the application code to change as well.
Here is a link to my public repo:
my demo app repo
Can someone please help me to understand what it is that I am doing wrong?
I want to follow a similar workflow as something like rpcs3, where whenever there is a new update for the emulator, there will be a pop when the user is using the application and if they want that new update, the application will restart and the users's application will reflect the most up to date patches from github.
Also, if you think there is another direction I could go in, please inform me! I am new to this process of updating versions and I just am not sure how to pull this off effciently the way that I want to.
packages need for my application:
pyqt5
requests

Below is my application file (my_qt_app.py) that has logic in it to detect a new version from github; again, the problem currently is that only the version_info.txt gets updated. I want the file "my_qt_app.py" to get updated as well when a new change is detected on github. Maybe it's because I do the git pull from within the application code? IDK lol please inform me if this is crazy and I need to approach it from a different angle :).
import requests, sys, subprocess
import platform
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt, QSettings
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QMessageBox

# Replace with your GitHub username and repository name
GITHUB_USERNAME = "malikcodergreen"
REPOSITORY_NAME = "version_updater_app"

# URL for the version info file
VERSION_INFO_URL = f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{GITHUB_USERNAME}/{REPOSITORY_NAME}/master/version_info.txt"

class HelloWorld(QWidget):
    def check_for_updates(self):
        print(f"Checking for updates")
        try:
            response = requests.get(VERSION_INFO_URL)
            latest_version = response.text.strip()

            # Replace with your logic to get current version (e.g., from a file)
            version_file = "version_info.txt"
            try:
                with open(version_file, "r") as file:
                    current_version = file.readline().strip()
            except IOError:
                raise IOError(f"Error opening version file: {version_file}")
        
            # Display an error message to the user
            if latest_version != current_version:
                message_box = QMessageBox()
                message_box.setWindowTitle("Update Available")
                message_box.setText(f"A new version ({latest_version}) is available! You're currently on version {current_version}.")
                message_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)

                try:
                    # Replace with your Git repository URL
                    repo_url = f"https://github.com/{GITHUB_USERNAME}/{REPOSITORY_NAME}.git"
                    button_pressed = message_box.exec_()     
                    if button_pressed == QMessageBox.Yes:
                        # update the existing version file
                        try:
                            with open(version_file, "w") as file:
                                file.write(latest_version)
                        except IOError:
                            raise IOError(f"Error writing to version file: {version_file}")
                        
                        subprocess.run(["git", "pull", repo_url])
                        # Option 1: Restart using a separate script (recommended)
                        self.close()
                        # Create a separate script (e.g., restart.bat or restart.sh) to relaunch the application
                        if platform.system() == "Windows":
                            subprocess.Popen(["restart.bat"])  # Windows example
                    
                        else:
                            subprocess.Popen(["restart.sh"])  # Linux/macOS example
                            print("Update pulled successfully. Restarting application...")
                    elif button_pressed == QMessageBox.No:
                        print("User declined update")
                        message_box.done(1)        
                        self.update_timer.stop()

            
                except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                    print(e.output)
                
                # Add an optional "Remind Later" button (custom button)
                # remind_later_button = message_box.addButton("Remind Later", QMessageBox.NoRole)
                # You can connect a signal to this button for later reminder functionality

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error checking for updates: {e}")

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set window title
        self.setWindowTitle("MY AWESOME NEW TITLE!")

        # Create a label widget
        self.label = QLabel("HELLO FROM BOOZ's WORLD", self)

        # Center the label in the window
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Set the window size
        self.resize(400, 300)

        self.skip_update = False
        # Schedule update check every minute
        self.update_timer = QTimer(self)
        self.update_timer.setInterval(600)  # Milliseconds in a minute
        self.update_timer.timeout.connect(self.check_for_updates)
        self.update_timer.start()

        # Show the widget (make the window visible)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = HelloWorld()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


When calling subprocess.run you should at least add the check=True argument to ensure that an error causes an exception. It would be even better to also capture the output for more information and possible error messages.

You should set up a webserver with a suitable file that your software can query, and optionally put it behind a CDN, and use that as a source for updates.  When you release a new version, your CI system can update that file as part of that version.  This can be very efficient if your client makes a request using a conditional request, such as If-None-Match or If-Modified-Since, since the web server and CDN will simply return a 304 Not Modified in such a case.
What you're doing here is using GitHub's raw file endpoints for this purpose.  Those exist for accessing a single file for occasional use, but are not intended for high-volume automated use, especially since they're subject to rate limiting.
In addition, your code doesn't gracefully handle any errors, such as a 429 Too Many Requests or a 403 Forbidden, both of which might indicate that you're being too aggressive and cause your code to break.
Git is also not a good tool to use for software updates or software distribution.  Your webserver that contains version data will probably want to contain some sort of JSON or CBOR file that includes multiple possible versions, including the latest one, and a location where an appropriate release tarball can be downloaded.  Note that if you're using GitHub for this, this tarball should be stored as a release asset, not from the autogenerated tarballs, which are also rate limited.
You'll also need to be able to verify a digital signature on your binaries when distributing them, since simply downloading random files from the Internet is not a secure or responsible way to distribute software.  You could do this either in the blob you get from the web server, using a manifest signed with a COSE (CBOR signing object) signature (or an external signature on the JSON blob), where the manifest for each item contains a secure cryptographic hash (such as SHA-256, but definitely not MD5 or SHA-1) to make sure the data isn't modified.  You'll need to include the public signing keys with your application so it can correctly verify the signature.
I might recommend putting a lot of this code in a separate module not inlined with the UI code, because you're going to want to test all of this—the status code handling, the manifest parsing, the signature handling—and that will make it much easier to test that you're doing the right things and things work as you expect.
